# Enabling Database Migrations with 2 Local Dbs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm after running into a problem with using Database-Migrations on my asp.net mvc project because I am using 2 local databases. I now have 2 databases; 1 which was created on project startup for identity user management like users, user roles etc. (aspnet-IdentityTest-201~). I Enabled-Migrations on this database in order to Seed() an admin member into it and everything was working fine.

The 2nd database was created after this using the code first database approach to store model data. Now my question, since my project already has migrations enabled (on the 1st Db), how do I enable migrations on my 2nd Db also? Currently when I run Update-Database, it targets 'aspnet-IdentityTest-20190707071058'. I would like to be able to run this command for my 'IdentityTest.Models.TestDb' also (with automatic migration enabled).

I'm afraid to run 'Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName IdentityTest.Models.TestDb' again as the last time I did this, it deleted my current config.cs file which included my Seed() for admins and I was left with a new config file for just the TestDb context. The project also failed to build after this

[image: a busy cat]

Could somebody please advise if there a way for my 2 databases to have migrations enabled? Do they have to share the same migrations/config.cs file? If this is not possible, using the code first approach; how do I make my project use aspnet-IdentityTest-201~ Db for storing model information instead of creating a new Db like it did with IdentityTest.Models.TestDb?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

First I took a solution where I successfully code firsted a db.  I changed all occurrences of my db name and suffix it with 2db.  I create another connection and call it {..}2 with catalog name {..}2dbSecond.  I then delete my Migrations folder.  I split out my context file into two contexts and have DbSet<> included in each appropriately.

typed:
enable-migrations -projectname contosouniversitydal -contexttypename schoolcontext
in the added migrations folder, in configration.cs, added the a seed method
Add-Migration InitialCreateContext1 -ProjectName contosouniversitydal -configurationtypename configuration -connectionstring schoolcontext
Update-database -projectname contosouniversitydal -configurationtypename configuration -connectionstringname schoolcontext

I then do the similar for the other context.

You can use https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference

Enable-Migrations has a -MigrationsDirectory option, so you can split among two different databases.